# Bind a complex class on MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following classes:

```
public class Movie
{
 string Name get; set;
 string Director get;  set;
 IList<Tag> Tags get; set;
}

public class Tag
{
    string TagName get; set;
}
```

On the Action of my controller I bind like this: `public ActionResult Create([ModelBinder(typeof(MovieBinder))]Movie mo)`

on theMovieBinder I convert the string to `List<tag>`. That when I debug works.

on the Movie binder I have the following code:

```
if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "Tags")
        {
            var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);
            if (values != null)
            {
                var p = values.AttemptedValue.Replace(" ", "");
                var arrayValues = p.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var list = new List<Tag>();
                foreach (string item  in arrayValues)
                {
                    list.Add(new Tag() { TagName = item });  
                }
                value = list;
            }
        }
```

But I get  the following Error  in the modelstate:
Exception = {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Models.Tag' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}

I create a Tag binder, but it does not work, any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What happened with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102850/modelbinding-asp-net-mvc-list/6102916#6102916 Didn't this work for you?

Comment: yes! Thanks! but Now I have this case.... where I create the Class Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the model binder I [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102850/modelbinding-asp-net-mvc-list/6102916#6102916) to this new situation where you have introduced the `Tag` class:

```
public class MovieModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "Tags")
        {
            var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);
            if (values != null)
            {
                return values.AttemptedValue.Split(',').Select(x => new Tag
                {
                    TagName = x
                }).ToList();
            }
        }
        return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that! but I get the error. When I debug it works. And even I see the Movie object and has correctly fill the properties. But when I do ModelState.isValid I get false. I will edit my code, in the question.

Comment: @elranu, yes indeed there is an issue. I've updated my answer to fix it. It works if you override the `GetPropertyValue` method in the model binder instead of `SetProperty`.

Comment: can you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240209/bind-on-edit-asp-net-mvc Thanks