# Bind on edit Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

on this question [ModelBinding asp.net MVC List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102850/modelbinding-asp-net-mvc-list) I was answered how to bind on a create action. But How I bind the same Movie class with it tags propertie on an edit action?

Because when I do this:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(string movieid)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieid))
        {
            ViewBag.Edit = true;
            var movie= db.GetCollection().FindOne(new { Name = movieid});
            if(movieid== null)
                throw new HttpException(404, "Movie not found");
            return View(movie);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

On the View at the input text I get: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

How I bind the list to an Input text, on the render of the view?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the first line of you view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can render your list of tags (string) in one textbox using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Tags, new { @Value = string.Join(",", Model.Tags) })
```

and if you have implemented custom model binder as Darin suggested in his answer you referred to, it will bind again to Tags lit on server side

Comment: this is ok. but there is any way to put that same code you write in a binder? for the edit mode?

Comment: Darin's modelbinder will work perfectly and bind comma separated values to list of string or do you mean to say htmlhelper?

Comment: Darin model binder work perfectly. But only on the create action. Not on the edit action, can I specifiy a binder for the edit action?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning

```
movie[0]
```

I believe you are returning a list of one movie instead of what the actual string value of the movie is.